# Inserir quebra de linha em texto em campo no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela com um campo tipo `text`, o campo armazena uma *string* importada via arquivo `.csv`, o mesmo foi inserido sem quebra de linha e estou tentando inseri-la, consegui identificar que a quebra de linha dever acontecer após o " - ", hífen espaço hífen, tentei esse trecho de código:

```
<?php

include('Connections/conexao.php');

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsPesquisa = "SELECT * FROM  `produtos` WHERE status = 1";
$rsPesquisa = mysql_query($query_rsPesquisa, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa);
$totalRows_rsPesquisa = mysql_num_rows($rsPesquisa);


do {

    $id_produto = 10;

    $string = $row_rsPesquisa['detalhes'];  

        if( strstr($string," - ")){         
            $novaString = wordwrap($string, 20, "<br />\n");            
            $UpDetalhe ="UPDATE produtos SET detalhes = $novaString WHERE id_produto = $id_produto;";
            $sucesso = mysql_query($UpDetalhe) or die(mysql_error("Erro ao alterar registro")); 

            if ($sucesso > 0) {
                echo "Próximo registro";
            }

        }

} while ($row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa));

?>
```

O texto sem formatação está assim:

"Medidas dos produtos da(s) foto(s) (cm): - 3 Lugares + Chaise: -   Largura: 281 -   Profundidade: 161 -   Altura: 94 - 3 Lugares: -   Largura: 225 -   Profundidade: 94 -   Altura: 94 - 2 Lugares: -   Largura: 170 -   Profundidade: 94 -   Altura: 94 - Modulado 2 Lugares + Canto + 3 Lugares: -   Largura (2 Lugares + Canto): 246 -   Largura (3 Lugares + Canto): 301 -   Profundidade: 94 -   Altura: 94 - Opções de tamanho: -   1 Lugar -   2 Lugares -   3 Lugares -   Modulado (assento, chaise e canto). -   Modelo também possui opção de puff. - Revestimento: -   Várias opções em tecido e couro sintético."

Após a minha tentativa ficou assim:

```
Medidas dos<br />
produtos da(s)<br />
foto(s) (cm):2<br />
Lugares: -  <br />
Largura: 212 -  <br />
Profundidade: 90 -  <br />
Altura: 86 - 3<br />
Lugares + Chaise: - <br />
 Largura: 212 -  <br />
Profundidade: 155 - <br />
 Altura: 86 -<br />
Opções de tamanho:<br />
-   2 Lugares -   3<br />
Lugares -   Modulado<br />
(assento, chaise e<br />
canto). -<br />
Revestimento: -  <br />
Várias opções em<br />
couro natural e<br />
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
Medidas dos produtos da(s) da(s) foto(s) (cm):
2 Lugares: 
- Largura: 212 
- Profundidade: 90 
- Altura: 86 
3 Lugares + Chaise: 
- Largura: 212 
- Profundidade: 155 
- Altura: 86 
- Opções de tamanho:
- 2 Lugares 
- 3 Lugares 
- Modulado (assento, chaise ecanto). 
- Revestimento: 
- Várias opções em couro natural e couro sintético.
```

Na exibição da variável em minha página estou usando isso, sem sucesso:

```
echo nl2br($row_rsProdutos['detalhes']);
```

Comment: <textarea name="teste" required>PONHA SEUS TEXTOS AQUI. O BANCO IDENTIFICARÁ AS QUEBRAS</textarea>

Comment: Olá @Lollipop, fiz o recomendado mas o texto ainda fica sem a formatação desejada, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Tem certeza que quer gravar os dados nesse formato num único campo da tabela no banco de dados? Existe um padrão nos dados .CSV, o qual vc poderia pensar numa modelagem simples e obter um controle melhor e organizado. Gravando dessa forma, sem uma mínima modelagem, terá um trabalho redobrado futuramente..

Comment: Olá @Daniel Omine, recebi essa planilha convertido em .csv do cliente.

Comment: @adventistapr.... vc entendeu o que postei?

Comment: Olá Olá @Daniel Omine, entendi sim, valeu pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tiver um padrão dá para fazer isto fácil. Se não tiver um padrão claro fica bem complicado ou impossível. Se não foi um erro de postagem sua (parece ser, afinal é impossível a fonte de dados dar o resultado que você disse desejar, os dados nem batem, são coisas diferentes) não dá para fazer exatamente como você postou, tem coisas foras do padrão ou o padrão é muito complicado e o algoritmo teria que ser igualmente complicado.

Se eu entendi o padrão dá para fazer isto:

```
<?php
include('Connections/conexao.php');

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsPesquisa = "SELECT detalhes FROM  `produtos` WHERE status = 1";
$rsPesquisa = mysql_query($query_rsPesquisa, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa);
$totalRows_rsPesquisa = mysql_num_rows($rsPesquisa);

do {
    $id_produto = 10;
    $string = $row_rsPesquisa['detalhes'];  

        if( strstr($string," - ")){         
            do {
                $posicao = strpos($texto, "-", 1);
                $linhaQuebrada .= ($posicao ? substr($texto, 0, $posicao) : $texto) . "\r\n";
                $texto = substr($texto, $posicao);
            } while ($posicao);

            $UpDetalhe ="UPDATE produtos SET detalhes = $linhaQuebrada WHERE id_produto = $id_produto;";
            $sucesso = mysql_query($UpDetalhe) or die(mysql_error("Erro ao alterar registro")); 

            if ($sucesso > 0) {
                echo "Próximo registro";
            }
        }
} while ($row_rsPesquisa = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPesquisa));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/tHXSd7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/StepLine). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/StepLine.php).

Note que eu peguei só o campo `detalhes`, se você só vai manipulá-lo não tem porque usar `*` no `select`, isto cria um enorme *overhead*.

Se o padrão não é bem este, explique melhor. Eu vi que tem uma diferença em algumas linhas que podem ser trabalhadas de outra forma. Ou seja, dá para separar a forma de tratar os produtos já que eles possuem um espaçamento extra. Mas precisa garantir que existe estes padrão. Sua postagem de como deve ficar não mostra um padrão claro.

E você precisa decidir se vai usar `<br>` ou `\r\n`. O código indica que é `<br>` e fiz originalmente assim. Sua edição diz que vai usar a quebra de linha de texto normal e depois vai converter para quebra de linha de HTML quando for apresentar. Sem consistência fica difícil entender o problema.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/bSix4v). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/StepLine2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/StepLine2.php). Poderia ter usado dois ternários mas ficaria menos legível.

Lembrando que se algum dado estiver mal formatado, não funcionará.

Comment: Olá @bigown, obrigado pelo excelente post, você tem razão, não tenho um padrão nesse campo detalhes, alguns registros podem ter 2 linhas, outras 3 e até como no exemplo postado.
Mas peguei o seu exemplo do Ideone e criei uma página e mandei para o meu servidor e o resultado não foi o mesmo, veja: http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/string.php

Comment: Me pareceu que o resultado é o mesmo. Pode dar mais detalhes do que você acha que é diferente? De qualquer forma teria que ver seu código para ter certeza se não tem nada diferente.

Comment: Veja esse link aqui: http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/string.php

Comment: Eu vi, está igual.

Comment: Que estranho na minha visualização da página as informação ficam em linha.

Comment: Como eu disse, sem olhar seu código real não posso dizer o que está errado. Olhe no navegador o código fonte desta página que você montou e veja que está certo. Você não montou um HTML, se quer apresentar tudo formatado, tem que fazer um HTML correto. Você disse na pergunta que está usando `echo nl2br($row_rsProdutos['detalhes']);`. Não acho que esteja usando na página gerada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20950/discussion-between-adventistapr-and-bigown).

Comment: Olá @bigown, me perdoe, você tem razão. estou a tanto tempo em cima dessa questão que já estou falando besteiras.
Obrigado pela grande ajuda.

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta @bigown, qual dessas variáveis mando guardar no meu BD, $texto $linhaQuebrada?

Comment: `$linhaQuebrada` olha lá no código: `"UPDATE produtos SET detalhes = $linhaQuebrada WHERE id_produto = $id_produto;"`

Answer (score 2):

`nl2br:` Insere quebras de linha HTML antes de todas newlines em uma string.
Sintaxe:
nl2br($string);

Funcionamento da coisa:
Ao dar “enter” para quebrar linha no campo textarea, esses “enters” são preservados e inseridos, junto com os dados, na base de dados.

**Exemplo:**

```
print "<p>".nl2br($produto['detalhes_do_produto'])."</p>";
```

**RESULTADO**

```
Estou testando esta área com quebra de linha
acabei de dar um enter
mais um
e mais um
```

fonte: http://www.linhadecomando.com/php/php-salvando-dados-com-quebras-de-linha-no-banco

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é através de uma expressão regular. Usando a função `preg_split()` você consegue separar a string a cada `-`. Funciona assim:

```
$string = $row_rsPesquisa['detalhes'];  
$id_produto = 10;

    if( strstr($string," - ")){ 
        $novaString = preg_split("/( - )/",$string); //vai retornar um array            
        foreach ($novaString as $pedaco){ //loop em todos os pedaços da string
            $UpDetalhe ="UPDATE produtos SET detalhes = $pedaco WHERE id_produto = $id_produto;";
            $sucesso = mysql_query($UpDetalhe) or die(mysql_error("Erro ao alterar registro")); 
        }
     }
```

Comment: Olá @Ricardo Lima Gonçalves, dei um print_r na variável $novaString e a mesma me retornou isso: Array ( [0] => /( - )/ )

Comment: Olá @Ricardo Lima Gonçalves, alterei a ordem do comando o correto é: $novaString = preg_split( "/( - )/", $string); //vai retornar um array.
Mas ainda não consegui fazer a alteração.

Comment: Editei minha resposta pra corrigir o código. Qual foi o resultado ao testar o código?